# Search box as a menu item in the nav menu output by wp_nav_menu?

Tags: menus, navigation

I am using the Twenty Twelve theme, and the following is the code it uses to register and display the menu.

**In functions.php:**

```
function twentytwelve_setup() {

    ...

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentytwelve' ) );

    ...

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentytwelve_setup' );
```

**In header.php:**

```
<nav class="site-navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
</nav>
```

And the output code looks similar to this:

```
<nav class="site-navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">

            <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9">
                <a href="http://aahank.com/">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12">
                <a href="http://example.com/">About</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

But I would like to modify the output so that a search box can be integrated into the navigation menu as  a menu item like so:

```
<nav class="site-navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">

            <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-9">
                <a href="http://aahank.com/">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li id="menu-item-12" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-12">
                <a href="http://example.com/">About</a>
            </li>

            <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-13">

                <!-- Search box inside nav as a menu item -->
                <form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">
                    <label for="s" class="assistive-text">Search</label>
                    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
                </form>

            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

How do I go about doing this? I need a code-backed pointer or two. Spoon-feeding is welcome too. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on : http://wpfirstaid.com/2010/10/extend-the-wordpress-menu/

```
function wpa_58902($items){
    $search = '<li class="search">';
    $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">';
    $search .= '<label for="s" class="assistive-text">Search</label>';
    $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
    $search .= '<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />';
    $search .= '</form>';
    $search .= '</li>';

    return $items . $search;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','wpa_58902');
```

Comment: more info to: http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/search-box-on-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 0):

I like better [this solution](http://zeaks.org/code-snippets/twenty-twelve-theme-search-form-in-header/):

In header.php:

```
</hgroup>
<div class="header-search"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div>
```

In style.css:

```
.header-search {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .header-search {
        margin-top:5px;
        text-align:center;
        float:none;
    }
    .main-navigation  {
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a long time after the question, but I had the same issue as mentioned in the question. I found no suitable solution in tutorials or on any stackexchange and in the end gave up and wrote my own code for it. I've since published it as a plugin:

[**Bop Search Box Item Type For Nav Menus**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bop-search-box-item-type-for-nav-menus/)

Crucially, this adds the search box as a menu item option like any other in the menu admin screen, and so no code needs to be added.

If you're after a more bespoke solution to you, there are some hooks that can be used (as detailed in the FAQ). Also, it's a very small, so you may want to use the code to make your own plugin, if you like.